# Checking availability of email registration asp.net+jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to check the availability of the email on keyup event. This is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var emailAlreadyExists = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=emailAlreadyExists]');
        var email = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=u_email]');

        email.keyup(function () {
            emailAvailability();
        });

        function emailAvailability() {
            $.post("Register.aspx/isValidEmail", { email: email.val() }, function (result) {
                if (result == true)
                    emailAlreadyExists.text("The e-mail is already taken");
                else 
                    emailAlreadyExists.text("Available");
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Here my code behind:

```
public bool isValidEmail(string email)
{
    UserBusiness user = new UserBusiness(u_email.Text);
    return user.emailExists(user);
}
```

> Well the problem is that I'm always getting the "Available" message of my label even if I try to type a e-mail which already exists in my database. As you can see, isValidEmail is a function which I get the result of my database (because I have the project divided in tiers, so I have the presentation tier, the business tier and date tier).? I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do what I want to. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: Is the correct email being sent back to the server-side code? Log the `email` param on the server, is it right?

Comment: I've checked everything and I think the mistake is at this line: $.post("Register.aspx/isValidEmail", { email: email }, function (result)  I think that the post is not working fine...

Comment: So, is the server-side function even being called

Comment: Now I'm totally sure, the problem is at that line I've mentioned before, because I deleted my function emailIsValid at code behind, and my label is still firing "Available" so... I don't know what I'm doing bad

Comment: What's your console say?

Answer (score 0):

my doubt,  there is scoping issue here...

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function () {
         var emailAlreadyExists = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=emailAlreadyExists]');
         var email = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=u_email]');

          email.keyup(function () {
              var Value=$(this).val();
               emailAvailability(Value);
          });



  });

 function emailAvailability(obj) {
        $.post("Register.aspx/isValidEmail", { email: obj }, function (result)
        {
               if (result == true)
                     emailAlreadyExists.text("The e-mail is already taken");
                else 
                      emailAlreadyExists.text("Available");
                });
         }
```

Comment: I still getting the same problem :(

Comment: i am not that into ASP.NET.. but i think.. the value posted form ajax is as `email` and `u_email.Text` if this is how you take the posted value in asp.net.. then i think that should be `email.Text` .anyways check in you server side code if you are getting the correct value or not...

Comment: I've modified my code to this: public bool isValidEmail(string email)
        {
            UserBusiness user = new UserBusiness(email);
            return user.emailExists(user);
        }

I made sure that I'm getting the correct value from my database, so I don't know where is the mistake... Any idea about that??

Comment: not much of .net guy... but what i am sure is the problem is in ,net function ...your value will be posted as `email` so you have to take the posted value as email.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your IsValidEmail function looks a bit odd.  It takes a parameter `email` but passes a parameter `u_email.Text` to the `emailExists` function. It's not clear where that comes from.

Also, your `emailExists` function seems to both be a method of the `user` object and requires a `user` object as a parameter. I suspect your problem is that function...can you post the code for it?

Comment: I've changed my function to this:  public bool isValidEmail(string email)
        {
            UserBusiness user = new UserBusiness(email);
            return user.emailExists(user);
        }  My functiont at UserBussines class is this: public bool emailExists(UserBusiness user)
        {
            if (uDate.emailExists(user.email))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }